Is this a proof for energy conservation?
I recently watched this video which proves energy conservation by defining kinetic energy as $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and potential energy as the negative integral of force with respect to position. The proof is derived from basic Newtonian mechanics. Here it is:
$$v^2 = u^2+2a(s_f-s_i)$$
$$v^2=u^2+2\left(\frac{F}{m}\right)(s_f-s_i)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{1}{2}mu^2 = F(s_f-s_i)$$
Here, the assumption is that force is constant from $s_i$ to $s_f$. However, this assumption can be eliminated by considering a small change in position $\Delta s$ such that $F$ is constant within this interval, even though it may be changing over the entire distance. Then:
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{1}{2}mu^2=\int_{s_i}^{s_f}F\cdot ds=\int_{0}^{s_f}F\cdot ds-\int_{0}^{s_i}F\cdot ds$$
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\int_{0}^{s_f}F\cdot ds=\frac{1}{2}mu^2-\int_{0}^{s_i}F\cdot ds$$
Now, if you define the potential energy to be the negative integral of force with respect to distance, we get:
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2+U_f=\frac{1}{2}mu^2+U_i$$
But I thought that energy conservation was an experimentally deduced fact. So I'm guessing there are some additional assumptions associated with this derivation, which makes this proof applicable to only a special subset of systems. What are these assumptions? And how far can you get with such an approach? In other words, how much can you generalize the energy conservation law using Newtonian mechanics?

I don't understand the issue you are facing. You have to define what energy is before you can both theoretically and experimentally verify it is conserved. Why is your proof at odds with experiments?

It may have started as an observation stemming from Newtonian mechanics, but energy conservation has become a far more general principle.
The most general or fundamental derivation I know of is using Noether's Theorem.  Discovered by mathematician Emmy Noether in the context of Lagrangian Mechanics, it can be shown that the postulate of Time Symmetry – that a physical experiment will have the same result regardless of being performed yesterday, today, or 100 years from now – directly implies conservation of energy. Likewise, linear physical symmetry (an experiment at my location has the same result as the same one performed 100 km to my right) directly implies conservation of momentum. And many other conserved quantities can be derived from a corresponding symmetry.
Importantly, it can be shown that in systems without Time Symmetry, such as the large scale structure of our universe, energy conservation does not hold. The universe is constantly expanding and changing such that an experiment 2 hours after the Big Bang would not give the same result as the same experiment now.  The microwave frequency light we observe in all directions has a peak frequency in the range of $10^{11} ~\mathrm{Hz}$ after 14 billion years of recession and redshift during the expansion.  When it was emitted it had a frequency of about $10^{14} ~ \mathrm{Hz}$.  That 1000-fold reduction in energy, by $E=hf$ is an example of energy non-conservation in a system without Time Symmetry.

Noether's Theorem is fine mathematics, but there's no proof that every physical system can be modeled by a Lagrangian. Energy conservation remains an experimental result, and it will always be so. Mathematical proofs require axioms, but nature doesn't give us axioms: it gives us phenomena.

Not a math expert, but when you mentioned "time symmetry" it made me think of reversibility.  I think systems that exhibit energy conservation will also exhibit symmetry in time.  So, in other words, they obey the same governing laws and look physically reasonable when played backwards in time.  Can't remember if this is restricted to Hamiltonian systems or if it generalizes to all conservative systems.

@JohnDoty It is deeper than that. If the universe is to be explored by science, charted with maths and physics, it must have energy conservation. If it doesn't, no observation has relevance and cannot prove or disprove anything.

@Stian Nonsense. If energy conservation was falsified by experiment, the necessary experimental conditions would hint at new patterns, and those could be explored.

@RC_23 When Emmy Noether proves that time symmetry of the Lagrangian implies conservation of energy, she only uses the fundamental laws of physics, isn't it? However, when one says that the Universe has no time symmetry, and thus that energy is not conserved, it seems that this is because one also considers the initial conditions (i.e. Big Bang, inflation, etc.) in addition to the laws. Why forget the classical distinction between the laws (e.g. the equations of motion), valid universally, and the accidental initial conditions? Aren't the laws sufficient for energy conservation?

@MarianoG You can have hamiltonian systems which to not have time reversal symmetry. A typical example would be to apply an external magnetic field (charged particle, gyromagnetic spin etc.). However, Noether's theorem still holds in this case. In this answer, the obscure "time symmetry" refers to time translation symmetry.

Interesting.  I guess I was thinking of Newtonian mechanical systems like rigid bodies. Good to know though.

@JohnDoty It remains to be seen then, which experiment you could concoct and conclude, while not being able to axiomatically assume that the universe is time-symmetric. Whatever answer you get is invalidized by the passing of the tiniest of seconds.

@Stian Imagine, for example, if you found a form of friction that generated no heat. And assume that it's reproducible.

@Michel in the simplest model of an expanding universe, the metric of spacetime is $d \tau ^2=dt^2+a(t)^2dS^2$. Because of the $a(t)$, the metric and thus the laws of physics, are time-dependent (not time translation invariant). So energy is not conserved. Likewise, even static metrics in GR are spatially dependent, and do not conserve momentum (at least not independently from stress-energy-momentum)

@RC_23 I agree that the metric is time-dependent, but I wouldn't say that it is a fundamental law of physics like the equations of Einstein for gravitation and general relativity, or those of Maxwell for electromagnetism: the metric of the universe is derived from general relativity and from the assumptions that the universe is homogeneous and isotropic; the latter are conditions added to the partial differential equations of Einstein. In classical mechanics, you don't need to consider boundary conditions to show that energy is conserved: the differential equations of motion suffice.

@MichelFioc For selected, conservative differential equations. No friction allowed. So, even mathematically, you've begged the question. And then, the only way to test your reasoning is via experiment.

@JohnDoty Right, the mechanical energy is not conserved with friction, but friction is not a fundamental interaction. As, theoretically (although not practically), all forces may be reduced to the four fundamental interactions and the latter are conservative, the total energy of an isolated system is still conserved if it is studied at the proper scale. As far as I know, friction, as all contact forces, is ultimately of electromagnetic origin, and the dissipation of energy caused by friction is an artifact due to the macroscopic description of the system.

@MichelFioc Friction is a ubiquitous physical phenomenon, easily accessible to experiment. That's as fundamental as anything gets in physics. Of course since Joule we have understood it to conserve energy even though a description of it in terms of differential equations does not.

@MichelFioc Theoretical abstractions are not fundamental: they are subject to change as more experimental results appear. The so-called fundamental interactions are not a complete description of physics. You cannot be certain that future refinements will include conservative differential equations.


But I thought that energy conservation was an experimentally deduced fact.

It is. That does not mean it cannot be derived mathematically. After all, it is agreed by many that mathematics is the language of physics ("Only through mathematics can one achieve lasting truth in physics. Those who neglect mathematics wander endlessly in a dark labyrinth." - Galileo).

So I'm guessing there are some additional assumptions associated with this derivation, which makes this proof applicable to only a special subset of systems.

As discussed by RC_23 his answer, there is the more fundamental concept of time-translational invariance. Another condition for energy conservation is that the force(s) involved must be conservative. In fact, Noether's theorem states that for a physical system with conservative forces, each symmetry of the action has a corresponding conservation law.

how much can you generalize the energy conservation law using Newtonian mechanics?

As much you like (in non-relativistic, classical systems as pointed out above by RC_23), provided all the forces involved are conservative.

Now, if you define the potential energy to be the negative integral of force with respect to distance

It's not a question of "if". It is necessary so that your result

$\frac{1}{2}mv^2+U_f=\frac{1}{2}mu^2+U_i$

naturally follows.
That is, for conservation of mechanical energy to hold true, the force(s) that bring about the changes in potential or kinetic energy, necessarily have the property that they can be written as the gradient of some potential energy function. This also means that the force is irrotational (zero curl) and that the work done is path independent (which also means that the line integral of the force over a closed loop will give you zero).

It can't be derived mathematically: as you point out, you must assume conservative forces, thus begging the question. We insist that the math conform to the experiments and observations, so of course it must manifest energy conservation if energy is seen to be conserved. Historically, the real power of the math here was to reveal that energy was something useful to keep track of, well before it even got the name "energy" (see "vis viva").

What that derivation shows is that $F=ma$ and conservation of the sum of potential and kinetic energy are related.
Those two are not independent cases: they are two ways to express the same thing.
Here's the thing: have you ever wondered why the expression for kinetic energy $\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2$ features that factor $\tfrac{1}{2}$?

What we have there is an expression with a squared quantity, and a factor $\tfrac{1}{2}$.
That combination of a squared quantity and a factor $\tfrac{1}{2}$ is typical for the outcome of evaluating the area between a slanted line and a horizontal line:
With cartesian coordinates, take the following simple graph: a straight line extending from the origin $(0,0)$, according to: $f(x) = x$
Next we give the expression for the area between that diagonal line and the $x$-axis, from the origin $0$ to a final point $x_f.$
The triangle with the base from $(0,0)$ to $(x_f, 0)$ is a right-angled triangle, which gives that the area between that graph and the x-axis is given by $\tfrac{1}{2}{x_f}^2$.

Now we take the following well known expression for uniform acceleration, with:

$s_f$ final position
$s_i$ initial position.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
s_f - s_i = v_i t + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2. \tag{1} 
\end{equation}
The factor $\tfrac{1}{2}$ of $\tfrac{1}{2}at^2$ correlates with the area of a triangle: with uniform acceleration the distance covered as a function of time is proportional to half the area of the rectancle with sides $t$ and $at$.
For later use:
\eqref{eq:2} for the relation that with uniform acceleration the velocity increases linear with time:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
v_f - v_i = at. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Multiply both sides of \eqref{eq:1} by $a$ for acceleration, and group the factor $(at)$ together:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
a(s_f - s_i) = v_i(at) + \tfrac{1}{2}(at)^2. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Use \eqref{eq:2} to substitute the factor $(at)$:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
a(s_f - s_i) = v_i (v_f - v_i) + \tfrac{1}{2}(v_f - v_i)^2 \tag{4}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:5}
a(s_f - s_i) = v_i v_f - {v_i}^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}{v_f}^2 - v_i v_f + \tfrac{1}{2}{v_i}^2 .\tag{5}
\end{equation}
The result is:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:6}
a(s_f - s_i) = \tfrac{1}{2}{v_f}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}{v_i}^2 \tag{6}.
\end{equation}
Both sides of \eqref{eq:6} can be interpreted in terms of area:

The left hand side is the area of a rectangle, $a(s_f - s_i)$
In the right hand side the factor $\tfrac{1}{2}{v_f}^2$ is the area of a right triangle with $v_f$ for the length of the base and $v_f$ for the height. Likewise for $v_i$.




Next:
To combine $F=ma$ and \eqref{eq:6}:
take $F=ma$, and multiply both sides by $(s_f - s_i)$:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:7}
F(s_f - s_i) = ma(s_f - s_i) \tag{7}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:8}
F \Delta s = \tfrac{1}{2}m{v_f}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}m{v_i}^2. \tag{8}
\end{equation}
The definitions of potential energy and kinetic energy are specifically chosen to slot in with the above.
Until around the 1850's physicists used a precursor to the kinetic energy concept that was called 'Vis Viva' (The living force), which was defined as $mv^2$.
It was around 1850 that a french physicist by the name of Gustave Gaspard Coriolis proposed a new name and a new definition: 'kinetic energy' and $\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2$. That innovation was adopted rapidly.
(Recognizing the value of defining a quantity $F\cdot \Delta s$ goes back all the way to Huygens. The interpretation of what it stands for changed over time, but not the definition.)

The point is: it is not a remarkable coincidence that $F=ma$ and conservation of the sum of potential and kinetic energy slot together: the definition of kinetic energy was specifically chosen to make that happen. The choice was made because physicists recognized how it makes a lot of things fall into place.



Generalizations
Generalization of \eqref{eq:6} to non-uniform acceleration.
First step.
Let there be two stages of uniform acceleration: from $s_0$ to $s_1$, and from $s_1$ to $s_2$.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:7a}
a(s_1 - s_0) = \tfrac{1}{2}{v_1}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}{v_0}^2 \tag{7}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:8a}
a(s_2 - s_1) = \tfrac{1}{2}{v_2}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}{v_1}^2. \tag{8}
\end{equation}
Add \eqref{eq:7a} and \eqref{eq:8a} together:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:9}
a(s_1 - s_0) + a(s_2 - s_1) = \tfrac{1}{2}{v_1}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}{v_0}^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}{v_2}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}{v_1}^2. \tag{9}
\end{equation}
On the left hand side the factor $s_1$ drops out and on the right hand side the factor $\tfrac{1}{2}{v_1}^2$ drops out.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:10}
a(s_2 - s_0) = \tfrac{1}{2}{v_2}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}{v_0}^2. \tag{10}
\end{equation}
This dropping out of intermediate terms generalizes to summation of a sequence of infinitesimally narrow rectangles, which of course is evaluation of an integral.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:11}
\int_{s_i}^{s_f} a \ \mathrm{d}s 
= \int_{v_i}^{v_f} v \ \mathrm{d}v \\
= \tfrac{1}{2}{v_f}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}{v_i}^2 \tag{11}
\end{equation}
(In \eqref{eq:11}, to go from the first to the second step:
$$\mathrm{d}s = v \ \mathrm{d}t \quad \text{and} \quad a \ \mathrm{d}t = \mathrm{d}v.$$
We have:
$$\int_0^s a \ \mathrm{d}s = \int_0^t a \ v \ \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^t v \ a \ \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^v v \ \mathrm{d}v$$).
Repeating \eqref{eq:11} with the inbetween step omitted:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:12}
\int_{s_i}^{s_f} a \ \mathrm{d}s = \tfrac{1}{2}{v_f}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}{v_i}^2. \tag{12}
\end{equation}
In mechanics the starting point is $F=ma$.
Integrating with respect to position coordinate, and using \eqref{eq:12} to process $\int m \ a \ \mathrm{d}s$:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:13}
\int_{s_i}^{s_f} F \ \mathrm{d}s \\
= \int_{s_i}^{s_f} ma \ \mathrm{d}s \\
= \tfrac{1}{2}m{v_f}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}m{v_i}^2 \tag{13}
\end{equation}

Generalization to areas other than mechanics
\eqref{eq:12} is not a physical property: it is a mathematical property.
Let me refer to not taking a derivative as 'zeroth derivative'.
If you have occuring together:
zeroth derivative
first derivative
second derivative, 
then there is a counterpart of \eqref{eq:12}.
Let $s$ represent any form of state that has a first time derivative and a second time derivative. Then:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:14}
\int_{s_i}^{s_f} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2s}{\mathrm{d}t^2} \ \mathrm{d}s = \tfrac{1}{2}{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)_f}^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)_i}^2. \tag{14}
\end{equation}

Example:
The case of electric current in a circuit:
change of current strength is the second derivative of position of charge.
A coil with self-inductance will oppose change of current strength.
Through an inductor: change of current strength is proportional to electromotive force (electric potential), divided by the coefficient of self-induction (inductance).
With:

$F_e$ electromotive force
$L$ inductance
$C$ position of charge
$I$ first time derivative: current,

\begin{equation}\label{eq:15}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 C}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{F_e}{L}, \tag{15}
\end{equation}
which can be restated as:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:16}
F_e = L \frac{\mathrm{d}^2C}{\mathrm{d}t^2}.  \tag{16}
\end{equation}
So when a current $I$ is flowing through an inductor, we expect an associated energy of $\tfrac{1}{2}LI^2.$
Generally:
In any area of physics where the dynamics is described with an equation that expresses that the second time derivative of some state relates to a particular change causing factor the relation \eqref{eq:14} can be used to transform the expression to energy form.

There are already great detailed answers, but staying in elementary level physics:

defining [...] potential energy as the negative integral of force with respect to position

The important experimental observation here is that this definition makes sense. You could imagine a universe with only two particles and only gravity, where bringing the two masses of 1 kg from 1 m distance to 10 m distance required a different amount of negative integral of force with respect to position, depending on how you did it. Defining "potential energy" in that way would still give the same result of energy conservation; however, to know the "potential energy" of a system you would need to know the entire history, so the concept wouldn't be very useful!
In other words, it's an experimental observation that the potential energy, defined in this way, is uniquely determined by looking at the current state of the system, regardless of history.
